# Reading ECU via XCP with RPi

Tags: raspbian, gpio, remote

Hello is it possible to connect my RPi with the ECU of lets say my car over OBD interface and XCP and if yes how would I start such a project?

I would like to apply remote analysis of my local computer via CANape and a distant RPi over the internet.

I thought about something like this:

1. Remote initialization of RPi and Computer
2. Figure out how XCP works
3. try to communicate between the data of CANape and my local computer (simulate port or something)
4. Receive Data from the OBD/ECU via raspberry
5. Communicate the Data between RPi and Local computer
6. send data back to CANape to analyze data received from RPi

If I am wrong here, could you please recommend me a site where I can ask these kind of questions?

Thank you.

Comment: This is a to generic/open question to fit this forum.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am sorry, is there a specific site where I receive answers suiting my question?

Comment: Car forums perhaps.